# How, if possible, can you chat using talk or write in the app Terminal?

Tags: terminal

I have heard you can send messages to other users in Terminal with the command "talk" or "write". If you can in fact do this, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command is just talk. It's disabled in OSX by default. See the comment at the end.

eg.

```
talk alex
```

It will then open a split screen and ping the other person to chat to you. They have to be logged into your computer at the same time though. Given that most Macs are single-user, this is unlikely, but possible. Have a friend connect in via SSH or screen-sharing and give it a go.

write allows you to write straight onto the other users console. By default though users have it disabled. You can turn it on with 'mesg y'.

```
write alex
```

Then type away to irritate the other user.

These are pretty old unix commands. Been around on linux/UNIX for years and years.

The man pages will help you too:

```
man write
man talk
man mesg
```

You can test this on one computer by creating a different ID and opening up Terminal with two windows. In the first window log back into your box with the other ID:

```
ssh otherid@localhost
```

Then write to the main users Terminal:

write mynormaluser

eg:

```
write alex
```

You'll see the text appear in window 2 of the Terminal

To get talk to work on OSX you need to enable it first. As root run this:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ntalk.plist
```

or, as a super user:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ntalk.plist
```

Comment: ok thanks. Is is possible to do with another computer? Tried the talk command but keeps saying "checking for invitation on caller's machine"

Comment: talk alex@anothermachinename   -- but, if you're going across the internet you'll probably be blocked by a firewall. On the local network that's less likely but still possible. It's not a command service to have running.

Comment: what is the machine name? Haha sorry- not too computer savy, maybe this is a dumb question

Comment: The bit after the @ sign. The name is whatever the hostname of the other computer is.

Comment: is the like the network it's on or what?

Comment: run hostname from Terminal. It'll tell you.

Comment: ok got it, still keeps saying it's checking for invitation on caller's machine".

Comment: It's off on OSX by default - see the note I added at the end.

Comment: says permission is denied.

Comment: Use the sudo version, assuming you're admin the box. Type in your regular password when it prompts.

Comment: ok perfect! now say waiting for party to respond and on other computer, the icon bounces in the dock and it shows a message is being started but how do I accept or respond? Is there a specific command?    Nevermind this comment- I found it! thank you again

Comment: It actually tells you how to accept. You type the reverse talk command. So, if userA is talking to you type talk userA

Comment: Also, why the need for ancient unix talking?

Comment: haha actually saw something like it on a tv show and my brother and i wanted to try it out ourselves